# Wrap certain types of lines to different text widths?

Tags: vim

I have text set to wrap at 80 characters.

Is it possible to have text wrapped to, say, 50 characters when editing a certain type of line?

For example, I program Ruby and I want Ruby comments to be wrapped to 50 characters whilst everything else stays at 80.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping is controlled by the `'textwidth'` option. `:help 'textwidth'` shows that it's *local to buffer*, so different values can be set, for example manually via

```
:setlocal textwidth=50
```

To make this automatically apply to all Ruby files, you can use Vim's built-in filetype detection and *filetype plugins*. Put the above command into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/ruby.vim`. (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`; use of the *after* directory allows you to override any default filetype settings done by `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/ruby.vim`.) Alternatively, you could define an `:autocmd FileType ruby ...` directly in your `~/.vimrc`, but this tends to become unwieldy once you have many customizations.

The built-in functionality stops there, at buffer scope. To apply the different textwidth only to *comments* (or any other syntax element), dynamic adaptation is needed. This can be implemented using `:autocmd`, hooking into the `CursorMoved` event. My [OnSyntaxChange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4085) provides utility functions to simplify the setup (again placed in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/ruby.vim`):

```
call OnSyntaxChange#Install('Comment', '^Comment$', 1, 'a')
autocmd User SyntaxCommentEnterA setlocal textwidth=50
autocmd User SyntaxCommentLeaveA setlocal textwidth=80
```

Comment: Thanks but I only want the setting to apply to comments not the whole of the Ruby file.

Comment: Oh, sorry, must have missed that. It requires a bit more effort; fortunately, I've written a plugin to simplify that. See my edit.

Comment: This is great. Thanks so much. Sorry for the mega-late response :)